# Persistent flag from LocalBridge.exe program

Tags: microsoft-office

I am getting a persistent flag from a program in the path Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub.../LocalBridge.exe .  The gist of the flag is "... incorrect parameter ..." but there is no evidence of any other software malfunction.  What should I do to stop the flag from occurring?  Would it cause a system problem if I delete the LocalBridge program?

Comment: What are you doing when you get that? Where do you see it? When it is doing what exactly? PLease clarify what you are asking with more detail and be more clear.

Comment: You can remove the app using `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub | Remove-AppxPackage` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

The error flag was associated with MS Office 365 apps.  I corrected the problem by booting in safe mode and repairing the Office app.  The flag has not occurred since.

Comment: ditto. I was unable to achieve any meaningful operation Safe Mode (??) but still did the MS Office online repair and the error has not returned

Comment: there was a duplicate Microsoft Office entry in the Settings | Apps list that was removed without incident. that may have contributed to the solution (along with the online Office repair) but it's unclear

Answer (score 1):

I ran across a computer that was receiving an error (Windows 10, 1809)

The customer had local admin and had installed updates manually through Windows 10 and had been upgraded to 1809 (most of our machines are on 1803 at this time)

```
"c:\Program Files\windowsapps\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_18.1910.1283.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
"C:\program files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftHub_18.1910.1283.0_x64..\" "The Parameter is Incorrect"
```

Repairing and reinstalling Office 365 (click to run) did not help.

My customer had installed Office applications through the Microsoft store and had Office 365 (2016 ver 1902) through SCCM.

I was able to resolve the error by removing the office apps from the Microsoft Store.